# How do I use the Z3Py dll?

Tags: python, dll, z3, smt, z3py

I tried to use the Z3Py dll, but it didn't work. Here are my test programs and errors. I am very new to Python, I think I missed some important part everybody already knows.

`init("z3.dll")`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test5.py", line 1, in <module>
    init("z3.dll")
```

NameError: name 'init' is not defined

[image]

[image]

I also tried another way to load the dll:

```
import ctypes
so = ctypes.WinDLL('./z3.dll')     #for windows
print(so)
s = Solver()

<WinDLL './z3.dll', handle 10000000 at 0x10b15f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test5.py", line 5, in <module>
    s = Solver()
NameError: name 'Solver' is not defined
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, all you have to do is import z3:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
x = Int("x")
s.add(x > 5)
s.check()
print s.model()
```

What happens when you run this simple script?

Comment: It works. I have already finished my progrem with import z3. Now I want to run it on a computer without z3py, so I tried dll.

Comment: You can't do that. The DLL contains the core functionality of Z3 (exported from C++), but you still need Z3py installed to have all the wrapper functionality. (Like the `Solver` class and all the other pythonic idioms around.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the function init() is used for loading the z3 core after imported?  Like z3.init()?

Comment: Whenever you refer to a Z3py function, the library will automatically initialize the DLL and make the core functionality available. This happens behind the scenes. In rare cases (say for a non-standard installation) you might have to explicitly call `init`, but this is definitely not the recommended way. In either case, you have to have the Z3py front-end installed on the computer; just having the DLL is not enough. See the very bottom of https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm

Comment: Inspired by you I think I found a way to run z3 without z3py installed. I find the library file, copy them to my local directory and renamed the folder as "z3local", and import them by `import z3local.z3 as z3`. And the test program worked perfectly even I uninstalled z3py.

Comment: That's what I would call a non-standard installation. Unless you've very good reasons to do otherwise, I would recommend against it. (For one thing, you'd have to repeat the same for each new release/bug-fix in official z3 itself.)

Comment: I'm just doing some experiments with Z3. So that's not a big deal. In one word, thank you very much. I think I realy learn some thing about Python.